# Is it possible to ask an anonymous question?

Tags: support, asking, user-accounts

I really want to ask an anonymous question, and I think I have seen a question by "Anonymous", so it possible to ask a question and mark it as anonymous?

Comment: You can ask to be disassociated with a question. This means it won't show your name, and you won't earn rep for it. The question I have is: why? What benefit would asking anonymously bring you, other than allowing you to ask an off-topic question without repercussions?

Comment: @Robotnik Maybe the question's about Panzermadels and he's embarrassed.

Comment: @Studoku I... wow. Just when I think I have the world figured out... I discover something like that. Thanks lol

Comment: @Robotnik Implying we haven't all been waiting for Panzermadels our whole lives

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible.

However, you can create another account and ask under that account. It isn't against the rules as long as you don't interact between the two (upvote each other etc.).